# JSON object building

Tags: android, json

Currently I have this JSON structure:

```
{"title1":["info1","info2"],"title2":"info2","title3":"info3"}
```

What I need to achieve is this:

```
{"title4":[{"a":"aa","b": "bb"}]}
```

To achieve the above, I use JSONArray:

```
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
    list.put("info1");
    list.put("info2");
    obj.put("title1", list);
```

And JSONObject:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("title2", "info2");
```

How can I visualize the desired output?

Comment: Do you mean that you are looking for code to achieve: `{"title4":[{"a":"aa","b": "bb"}]}`?

Comment: Yes, I need that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, a `JSONObject` with a `JSONArray` containing `JSONObjects`, you can use the following code

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject(); // The root JSON object

JSONArray title4 = new JSONArray(); // The JSON array that will contain JSON objects

// The JSON objects
JSONObject a = new JSONObject();
a.put("a", "aa");

JSONObject b = new JSONObject();
b.put("b", "bb");
title4.put(a);
title4.put(b);

// Put the JSON array in the root JSON object
root.put("title4", title4);
```